# How to make layout same while using border

Tags: css

When we use border it apply outside of element. If I create div of 100px width and add 10px border than its overall with will be 120px and that's why layout will be not good since this extra unwanted width due to width cause problem in float and fluid layout

[image]

to solve this problem If I want to create 100px div with 10px border I create div of 80px and than 10px border so its total width will be 100 however its not I want since if I just want to change size in border or div I need to change both

it there any way I can create div 100 px and apply 10px border and overall width will be 100px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classically solved this way with a CSS2 / IE5,5/6 compat solution by putting two divs inside each other:

```
<div class="size">
    <div class="border">
        Give me some border ;)
    </div>
</div>
```

In the CSS you make use of the *size*-div to set the size and the *border*-div to set the border:

```
.size {width:200px; height:200px;}
.border {border:10px solid blue;}
```

So even if you only know the standard box-model you can solve this.

[image]

See http://jsfiddle.net/6K2vS/ for an online demo of this.

In some really old browsers you sometimes even need to set a zero-width border to the outer element to have this working. Just noting if you look for some backwards compatible solution.

Comment: This totally goes against separating design and content and adds unnecessary HTML elements.

Comment: @powerbuoy: Not really, especially as the `<div>` element is immune to such saying. And with CSS2 there is no other way to go around the browser quirks in a streamlined (and stable) fashion as outlined. It's useful for many other CSS related processings, too, in case you need to create stable code. And to separate design and content you should nowadays not use HTML and CSS alone. Both parts are normally generated in an intermediate step to better separate design and content. Which renders your argument even more moot.

Comment: `div` has no semantic meaning - that doesn't mean that div:itus and class:itus isn't a problem. What you're proposing is div:itus. And your class names are really design related as well. What's the point in using CSS2 when 3 is out? `box-sizing` works well in everything above IE7.

Comment: You are reading much too much out of those exemplary lines of code. And just FYI: It even works below IE7, try it out ;).

Answer (score 3):

There is. You can use `box-sizing: border-box` on the element and the width (and height) will be calculated the way IE did it in quirksmode.

It can be extremely useful sometimes, but imo it's good to learn how the normal box model works and get used to working with it first.

Fwiw I've built a site using `box-sizing: border-box` as default on *all* elements and I would actually not recommend it. Partly because *I*'m really used to the normal box-model but mostly because there are still bugs with `box-sizing` in some browser (FF and percentages I remember messing up).

Edit: Note that it doesn't work in IE<8.
Edit2: More here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: +1 I learned something :) I also agree with your suggestion that OP should get used to the standard.